# how can i solve yarn's installation error

Tags: yarnpkg

I'm trying to install yarn but everytime it's this same error:

```
yarn
yarn install v1.15.2
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/react/-/react-16.8.6.tgz: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "C:\\laragon\\www\\demo\\yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
```

Comment: can you tell us anything more about your environment

Comment: I’m using windows 10 64bits 500Go and 4Go RAM